# How to prolong the life of kids shoes, worn on the toe?

Tags: shoes

As a parent I see that my kids' shoes get worn out on the toes first.

Is there a way to prolong the life of the shoe, either by protecting the toe area, or repairing it?

I tried a small piece of fabric tape on the end, but it didnt work so well (tape came off, or got easily worn through).

Any tips are appreciated.

PS. note that I live in Europe, where going to the cobbler / shoe repair shop is insanely expensive, to the point where it's almost better to buy new shoes than going there.

[image: Kids shoes get worn on the toes]

Comment: do they play soccer? or any other activity involving kicking stuff?

Comment: No. they have separate shoes for soccer. We have asked them not to use the toes as brakes on the scooters, and they respect that wish mostly. Theres just a large amount of wear and tear from normal play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a product called "Shoe Goo" with which you can coat the tear.  Google it and you will find lots of outlets as well as instructions for making the repair.    Knowing the kids predisposition for scraping the toes, when you get new shoes, coat the toes with Shoe Goo before he gets it scuffed --- the scuff will be on the coating and protect the shoe underneath.  It's great stuff.

Comment: Thanks I ordered one for $7 plus $8 for international shipping. Considering that kids shoes typically cost $30-$40 here in Europe, spending $15 seems reasonable. I'll come back and accept one of the answers here when I've tried the Shoe Goo.

Comment: I received the shoe goo and applied it to the front of the shoe. It is completely transparent and barely noticeable. About 1-2 millimeters and quite hard, it should protect the toes.

Comment: Still using my first tube of shoe goo on my kids shoes. Prolongs the life of the shoes by 6 months, by my estimates :)

Answer (score 3):

Use an ***EPOXY COATING***

Visit a Hardware Store for an Epoxy Coating which you "paint" on the worn area.
Let the application cure thoroughly overnight.

The layer is light in weight, not bulky to trip the wearer otherwise, is easy to apply, is transparent, can be applied before (to prevent) or after (to repair) damage. Can be re-applied as often as necessary.

The two parts consist of
1) an epoxy resin which is cross-linked with
2) a co-reactant or hardener.

Mix-up and apply as much as necessary with no waste.

Epoxy coatings are formulated based upon the performance requirements for the end product.

When properly catalyzed and applied, epoxies produce a hard, chemical and solvent resistant finish.

Answer (score -2):

Only real solution, teach your child not to use the top of the shoe in contact with the ground for anything.
I have seen many a child on a balance bike, and fewer but still too many on peddled bikes, who use the top of their shoes as a kind of brake or just have the foot be dragged over the ground while still moving.

I was one of them, when I was small, I remember my mother telling me, likely over and over again, to be more careful with my shoes.

If you think your child is not trainable (yet) you can try adding a patch of thick leather. It needs to be sturdy leather, need to be connected to the shoe securely. At least glue but best is to also sew it.
And it is not a real solution.

One way of not getting holes in that position is to buy open toe shoes for the child, sandals in other words.
That will teach them not to drag their foot top down, as it will start hurting soon.

Comment: Well we've done our best to ask them not to use the toe when braking - have reduced the rate of wear, but they still wear out on the toe nonetheless. How would you suggest obtaining an appropriate piece of leather? For example from an old handbag or jacket?

Comment: I was thinking belt leather, of a belt that is 2 mm or more thick.